# If value between array key

Tags: php

Example i have this array:

```
$ar = array(
    "1.00" => array("value0"," very bad"),
    "1.49" => array("value1","bad"),
    "2.00" => array("value2","not bad"),
    "2.49" => array("value3","normal"),
    "3.00" => array("value4","good"),
    "3.49" => array("value5","very good")
 );
```

I want to check if $val is under 1.00  the $result is array("value0"," very bad"). if between range 1.00 - 1,49 the result is array("value1","bad"), etc.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: have you tried anything? what have you tried? what in particular are you stuck on?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint :

```
<?php

$ar = array(
    "1.00" => array("value0"," very bad"),
    "1.49" => array("value1","bad"),
    "2.00" => array("value2","not bad"),
    "2.49" => array("value3","normal"),
    "3.00" => array("value4","good"),
    "3.49" => array("value5","very good")
 );


$input = 1.2;

foreach($ar as $key=>$text)
{
  if($input < floatval($key))
    {
      echo $text[0].' => '.$text[1];
      break;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$val = '2.15';
$val_data = ['value2','not bad'];

$data = array(
    "1.00" => array("value0"," very bad"),
    "1.49" => array("value1","bad"),
    "2.00" => array("value2","not bad"),
    "2.49" => array("value3","normal"),
    "3.00" => array("value4","good"),
    "3.49" => array("value5","very good")
);

$_fkey = array_keys($data)[0];
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    if($key > $_fkey && $key < $val){$_fkey = $key;}
}

echo "$val, $val_data\n";
echo "=> $f_key, " . $data[$f_key] . "\n";
```

Comment: i am tried and always give result array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "value0" [1]=> string(9) " very bad" }

Comment: i tried but still error, btw i have solved problem by answer of sdespont. thank you